# chained async rest calls feeding follow on functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, sharepoint-2013

** Update: The answer below works great up to the merge. I had to add some iterations into getL2 and getL3 to make all the calls necessary. The issue seemed to be that some of the tasks from L1 did not have a child at L2, and some L2 did not have an L3. So the final results has some empty arrays. the final result before the merge looks like below. right now, the merge function returns the L1 data with no children added.

```
var result = [
  [{
    "ID": 1,
    "title": "Task 1",
    "org": "A"
  }, {
    "ID": 2,
    "title": "Task 2",
    "org": "B"
  }],
  [{}, {},
    {
      "ID": 10,
      "ParentID": 2
    }, {
      "ID": 11,
      "ParentID": 2
    }
  ],
  [{}, {}, {
    "ID": 20,
    "ParentID": 10
  }, {
    "ID": 21,
    "ParentID": 10
  }]
]
```

I continue to struggle with async and promises, despite the amazing help on stack. I tried to reverse engineer some similar posts with no success. I am trying to chain 3 functions that will make multiple REST calls in SharePoint 2013. the first call grabs all items in list taskL1 that match the organization. it uses the ID's to create a set of unique entries. then a second call against taskL2 is made using the the set to find all entries that have those id's in the parentID column. It then creates a set of those IDs to make a final call against taskL3 and matches those IDs to the parentID column in that list. I need to pass all three results along until a final function will merge the data into a nested object.Bascially, put all the L3 tasks under the correct L2 and all the L2 under the correct L1. I can't seem to keep all 3 results passing along until the end and available to a follow on function. https://jsfiddle.net/75ghvms8/

```
var setL1 = new Set();
var setL2 = new Set();

var taskL1 = [{"id":1,"title":"Task 1","org":"A"},{"id":2,"title":"Task 2","org":"B"},{"id":3,"title":"Task 3","org":"A"}]
var taskL2 = [{"id":20,"parentID":1},{"id":21,"parentID":1},{"id":22,"parentID":2},{"id":23,"parentID":2}]
var taskL3 = [{"id":100,"parentID":20},{"id":111,"parentID":21},{"id":120,"parentID":22},{"id":220,"parentID":23}]

getL1(taskL1,'A').then(()=>{getL2(taskL2,setL1)}).then(()=>{getL3(taskL3,setL2)});

async function getL1(srcList,org){
    const l1List = await getData(srcList,org);
  console.log(l1List);
  return l1List
  }
async function getL2(srcList,set){;
    const l2List = await getData2(srcList,set);
  console.log(l2List);
  return l2List
  }
async function getL3(srcList,set){
    const l3List = await getData3(srcList,set);
  console.log(l3List);
  return l3List
  }
  
async function getData(srcList,org,result={}) {
    const listItems = await getTaskItems(srcList,org);
  result = listItems;
  return result;
}

async function getData2(srcList,item,result={}) {
  let j = 0;
  for(let i of item) {
    const listItems = await getTaskItems2(srcList,i)
    result[j] = listItems;
    j++
    }
  return result
}

async function getData3(srcList,item,result={}) {
  let j = 0;
  for(let i of item) {
    const listItems = await getTaskItems3(srcList,i)
    result[j] = listItems;
    j++
    }
  return result
}

function getTaskItems(srcList,org) {
  const arrData = srcList.filter(obj=> {
    return obj.org === org;
  });
    for (let i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    setL1.add(arrData[i].id);
        }
 return {arrData,setL1}
}

function getTaskItems2(srcList,id) {
  const arrData = srcList.filter(obj=> {
    return obj.parentID === id;
  });
    for (let i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    setL2.add(arrData[i].id);
        }
        return {arrData,setL2}
}

function getTaskItems3(srcList,id) {
    const arrData = srcList.filter(obj=> {
      return obj.parentID === id;
    });
    return arrData;
  }
// real functions are spRest-Lib functions 
/*
function getTaskItems(srcList, org) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
    sprLib.list(srcList).getItems({
      listCols: {
        columns here
        }
    })
      .then(function(arrData){
        for (let i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
          setL1.add(arrData[i].ID);
        }
        resolve(arrData);
      })
      .catch(function(errMsg) {console.log(errMsg);});
    })
  }
*/
```

Comment: It looks like some of the function params are really "output params" to collect results, but the functions also return objects.  The chain of `.then(() => ` near the top of the code ignores the return values.  This isn't quite an answer, but it's the start of one. Start by making the functions more functional: have functions take input params only and return results. The callers should get everything they need in the return values.  `then` blocks that need the promise result should have a dummy param and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tweak some key names. Promise chaining is achieved by returning custom objects `{l1: [], l2: [], l3: []}`. Merge can probably be done as you go along each step, but instead here is one way to do it with explicit merge step.

```js
var taskL1 = [{"id":1,"title":"Task 1","org":"A"},{"id":2,"title":"Task 2","org":"B"},{"id":3,"title":"Task 3","org":"A"}]
var taskL2 = [{"id":20,"parentID":1},{"id":21,"parentID":1},{"id":22,"parentID":2},{"id":23,"parentID":2}]
var taskL3 = [{"id":100,"parentID":20},{"id":111,"parentID":21},{"id":120,"parentID":22},{"id":220,"parentID":23}]
 
async function getL1(org) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // assuming some external reqeust
        resolve({ l1: 
            taskL1.filter((item) => item.org === org) 
        });
    })
}

async function getL2(l1Result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const allL1Ids = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(l1Result.map((item) => item.id)))); 

        // assuming some external request
        const filteredList = taskL2.filter((item) => allL1Ids.indexOf(item.parentID !== -1));

        resolve({ l1: l1Result, l2: filteredList});
    })
}

async function getL3(l1Result, l2Result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const allL2Ids = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(l2Result.map((item) => item.id)))); 

        // assuming some external request
        const filteredList = taskL3.filter((item) => allL2Ids.indexOf(item.parentID !== -1));

        resolve({l1: l1Result, l2: l2Result, l3: filteredList})
    })
}


function groupByKey(items, key) {
    return items.reduce(function(results, item) {
        (results[item[key]] = results[item[key]] || []).push(item);
        return results;
    }, {});
}

function merge(l1, l2, l3) {
// we want to put l3.parentID into l2.id.children
  let l3ByParentId = groupByKey(l3, "parentID");
  let l2ById = groupByKey(l2, "id"); 

  Object.keys(l3ByParentId).forEach((parentId) => {
    if (l2ById[parentId]) {
        l2ById[parentId][0]['l3children'] = l3ByParentId[parentId];
    }
  });
  
  let l2ByParentId = groupByKey(Object.values(l2ById).map((item) => item[0]), "parentID");
  let l1ById = groupByKey(l1, "id"); 
  Object.keys(l2ByParentId).forEach((parentId) => {
    if (l1ById[parentId]) {
        l1ById[parentId][0]['l2children'] = l2ByParentId[parentId];
    }
  });
  
  return Object.values(l1ById).map(item => item[0]);
}

getL1("A")
.then((result) => {
    return getL2(result.l1)
})
.then((result) => {
    return getL3(result.l1, result.l2)
})
.then((result) => {
    return merge(result.l1, result.l2, result.l3)
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
})
```

Comment: this works great. however there is an issue with the merge function due to the nature of the data. I have clarified above.

Comment: If you run the code snippet above, what’s the output and how does it differ from the expected output? In the example data there is no l2 data with parent ID 3, hence the empty children.

Comment: I got it working with a different merge function. The issue was that that the results in l2 and l3 were nested arrays with holes. Once I flattened to one dimension, I was able to iterate over each result and push it into a new entry for l2 and l3 within l1.